# What's the best way to handle local user accounts on cordova/phonegap?

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

Basically, I want to create user accounts which will be saved locally(via localStorage). This will serve as the authentication for the app. In order to log in to the site, the users will have to create or select existing account. What's the best way to handle user accounts that are created locally?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create database same as MySQL into/using [SQLite Plugin](http://phonegappro.com/tutorials/phonegap-sqlite-tutorial-with-example-apache-cordova/) ( <-Here are all the examples of sqlite plugin you need to use) in cordova application.

Using this you can perform login/register operations, but make sure this is same as localStorage, so the created Ids works only for single current device for that app.